# How to display audit trail on a ballon

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have created Audit trail and it works fine. you can see all the changes and even the name of the table edited. Now i want to display changes on the popup. Once the user edit some fields, i want to display fieldname,oldvalue,newvalue,username and date.Only once you click on the balloon.

I have no idea on how i can do that. I have implemented the balloon which you can click and view the changes but it doesn't work.

How can i display all the changes on the balloon

Ballon i have created: i have customize it the way i want it if there's an edit

```
<div class="small-chat-box fadeInRight animated">
    <div class="left">
        <div class="author-name">
            Claim Edit <small class="chat-date">
                <br>09-06-2016 12:00 pm
            </small>
        </div>
        <div class="chat-message active">
            Username: JJ
            <br>fieldname: Surname
            <br>oldvalue: small
            <br>newvalue big
            <br>date: @DateTime.Now
        </div>
    </div>
 </div>
```

my audit method which works fine

```
 public static List<ClaimAudit> GetClaimLog(SidDbContext db, int claimId)
    {
        --------------------
             foreach (var entry in changeTrack)
        {
            if (entry.Entity != null)
            {
                string entityName = string.Empty;
                string state = string.Empty;
                switch (entry.State)
                {
                    case EntityState.Modified:
                        entityName = ObjectContext.GetObjectType(entry.Entity.GetType()).Name;
                        state = entry.State.ToString();
                        foreach (string prop in entry.OriginalValues.PropertyNames)
                        {
                            object currentValue = entry.CurrentValues[prop];
                            object originalValue = entry.OriginalValues[prop];
                            if (!currentValue.Equals(originalValue))
                            {
                                ClaimLogs.Add(new ClaimAudit
                                {
                                    tableName = entityName,
                                    state = state,
                                    fieldName = prop,
                                    oldValue = Convert.ToString(originalValue),
                                    newValue = Convert.ToString(currentValue),
                                    userId = "JJ",
                                    UpdateDate = DateTime.Now,
                                    CommentsId = 1,
                                    ClaimId = claimId

                                });
                            }
                        }
                        break;
                }
            }
        }
```

calling my update function on save

```
public async Task<bool> UpdateClaimVehicle(ClaimVehicle vehicleModel)
    {
        List<ClaimAudit> ClaimLogs = new List<ClaimAudit>();
        using (IBaseDataRepository<ClaimVehicle> bs = new BaseRepository<ClaimVehicle>())
        {

            using (SidDbContext db = new SidDbContext())
            {
                if (vehicleModel != null)
                {
                    var oldClaim = db.ClaimVehicles.FirstOrDefault(x => x.ClaimId == vehicleModel.ClaimId);

                    oldClaim.VehicleMakeModelId = vehicleModel.VehicleMakeModelId;
                    oldClaim.VehicleRegistrationNumber = vehicleModel.VehicleRegistrationNumber;
                    oldClaim.VehicleYearModel = vehicleModel.VehicleYearModel;
                    oldClaim.VinNumber = vehicleModel.VinNumber;

                    ClaimLogs = GetClaimLog(db, oldClaim.ClaimId);
                    db.claimAuditLog.AddRange(ClaimLogs);
                    db.SaveChanges();  
                }
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
```

Here i was trying to display it on the view first,but it says model does not exist

```
      @model Business.Models.ClaimDetailsModel
       @foreach (var item in Model) //error here
        {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ClaimId)
            </td>
        </tr>
        }
```

Comment: Just to be clear, you are successfully able to retrieve the old values.. the problem is that you want to display those old values on the balloon?

Comment: @BviLLe_Kid I am able to see all the changes made by checking on the database and all works fine. there's no were i am displaying those changes currently

Comment: Have you tried using ViewBags?

Comment: I have tried to display them but it says Model does not exist.
     
but the requiments is to display it on the ballon. just like a message. check my edited code

Comment: Just as a test, try `ViewBag.Test = oldClaim.VinNumber`.. then in your view... `oldValue: @ViewBag.Test`

Comment: Please check my update code and direct me to the right direction

Comment: okay the problem is, is that you are using a `foreach` loop on your Model which is not a *collection* type.. so in order to use that foreach loop you need to change the model to `@model IEnumerable<Business.Models.ClaimDetailsModel>`

Comment: The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'BusinessLogic.Models.ClaimDetailsModel', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[BusinessLogic.Models.ClaimDetailsModel]'.

Comment: In your controller, whatever you are returning.. I am assuming something like `return View(/*object that is of type ClaimDetailsModel*/);`  That item that you are returning needs to be a type of `List<ClaimDetailsModel>`

Comment: Got it..but how can i get to display it on the balloon as per requiments

Comment: IDK if when you created your controllers, you auto generated the views as well... but if you did this is the same thing as the *Index ActionResult* and the *Index View*.. In the *Index ActionResult* method in your controller you are returning a list, and your *Index view* is expecting a List with `@model IEnumerable</*blah blah blah*/>`

Comment: From my experience, if you want to display things from the controller you are going to have to use dynamic types, such as `ViewBag`

Comment: I am very new to mvc and am trying to learn as fast as i can but this task it's a mountain to climb for me. can you please just give me example of what you saying looking at my codding. please

Comment: so find the old Record.. which you already did with `var oldClaim = db.ClaimVehicles.FirstOrDefault(x => x.ClaimId == vehicleModel.ClaimId);`.. so then use `ViewBags`.. for example `ViewBag.oldVin = oldClaim.VinNumber`, then in your View just call `@ViewBag.oldVin`

Comment: I don't get you. can you please try to implement on my code so that i can see clearly?

Comment: Check this out: [.netFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/wmoHk9)  I made the ViewBag in the controller and in the view.

Comment: Which means i will do the viewbag on the controller which am updating on? and thenon the view i will just pass it like the date?

Comment: But when i try to add the ViewBag on the controller wich updates, it doesn't find ViewBag

Comment: What do you mean it doesn't find it?

Comment: I have tried this code and it is not working, not even getting the fields i want to pass 

[HttpGet]
        public ActionResult _AuditLog(ClaimAudit auditmodel)
        {
            using (SidDbContext db = new SidDbContext())
            {
                Client oldClaim = db.Client.FirstOrDefault(x => x.ClaimId == auditmodel.ClaimId);

                ViewBag._oldvalue = auditmodel.oldValue;
                ViewBag._newvalue = auditmodel.newValue;
                ViewBag._tablename = auditmodel.tableName;
               
            }  
            return View();
        }

Comment: Have you debugged those values? To ensure that you are getting the values you are expecting?